# How to disable the animation of the datalabels on a pie chart with HIghcharts?

Tags: highcharts, phantomjs

I have a page running a couple of charts done with HighCharts. I'm also running PhantomJS to save the pages as PDFs. Due to the way PhantomJS works, I need to disable all of the animations on HighCharts to allow it to save the page correctly. Problem is, I can't find a way to disable the animation of the datalabel on a Pie chart. The plot animation is disabled, the chart animations are disabled, but the datalabels are still animated (coming from the left of the page to sit on its correct location). How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set the `series.animation` to `false` as well. See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-animation-disabled/).

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        animation: false
    }
},
```

Note that I am not able to test if the `dataLabels` animate or not. I have not seen them animate.

Comment: It is set to false already. The series animation itself (the pie slices rotating) is disabled, but the animation of the datalabels is not. I will Edit the question to add my code to it

Answer (score 0):

So I found the issue, it is not on the Highcharts main sourc. I'm using Dojo, and not jQuery, so I installed [this adapter](http://www.dojotoolkit-fr.org/2012/04/highcharts-dojo-adapter/?ModPagespeed=noscript). Problem is, that adapter adds the animation, and not HighCharts itself. I realized it when I created the jsFiddle, and saw that using jQuery was giving a different behavior than using dojo.